# Incremental Load

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables order, order-line.
I am doing an inner join of these 2 tables to get some kpis into a dashboard facing table order-kpis.

I have attached an example of how the data looks in each of the table by day.

Say on day-1, we have a couple of orders in the order table with their respective lines in the order-line table. Day-1 first time load works fine.

On day-2, I just get an additional order-line for one of the orders. How can I drive an incremental load for only the record which has changed?

I can process last n days of data which will solve this but we have about 60 odd systems and 60 different parameters if we go with this approach and it is difficult to get an answer on this.

Is there any out of the box solution or should I write some custom logic to get this done?[image]

Comment: Please post some sample data not images.

Comment: Just run the entire query on day 2.  There is not advantage to trying to optimize such a query that runs once per day.